# Laravel - My code works on Firefox and Chrome, but still error in Safari

Tags: php, laravel

Previously, I type error code on my Laravel email blade file like this:

```
    {{ date('d M Y', strtotime($transaction->created_at)); }}
```

The error happens on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox browsers. When I remove the semicolon, this code work on **Chrome and Firefox, but still show the same error in Safari** even after I changed the code.

[image]

Sorry for the bad image, I'm new in Laravel so I don't have an idea how to debug email with data hehe. This is what I'm getting from the browser network inspection response.

I've tried the following command to clear the Laravel project:

```
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan view:clear
```

But the error still happens. Does anyone have a suggestion about it? I'm using Laravel 5.8 version btw

Thanks!

Comment: The PHP syntax doesn’t change, just because a different browser makes the request. I am guessing, most likely you are getting fooled by your browser cache here.

Comment: I've tried private mode too bro. that's weird :( @CBroe